# Why python call by reference is so unruly

Tags: python

```
arr = [1]

def f1(lst):
    lst.append(2)
    print(lst)
    lst = 2
    print(lst)

f1(arr)
print(arr) # [1,2]
```

why python call by reference parameter does not change to value?

what does lst variable indeicating when do "lst = 2"
(not connected to arr?)

Comment: Python doesn't have "call by reference". You cannot reassign the value of a variable at the callsite by assigning the value of a variable in a function.

Comment: Python does not have call by reference. This is very important to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Assigning `lst = 2` doesn't affect the value of `arr`. In fact, python doesn't do "call by reference" at all.

Answer (score 0):

Annotating your code with comments that might help clear it up:

```
arr = [1]

def f1(lst):
    # lst and arr both refer to the same [1] list at this point.
    # Two different and independent names for the same object.
    lst.append(2)  # appends 2 to [1], aka lst, aka arr
    print(lst)     # lst/arr is now [1, 2]
    lst = 2        # reassign the name 'lst' to the value 2!
    # At this point, lst refers to 2 instead of [1, 2].
    # lst and arr are no longer connected.
    # arr is still [1, 2] even though lst is 2.
    print(lst)     # indeed, lst is now 2
    # but arr is still [1, 2], as seen below:

f1(arr)
print(arr) # [1,2]
```

https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html is highly recommended reading on this topic!  The main thing to understand is that `lst` and `arr` are just different *names* that at different points in the code might refer to the same value or different values.

When you call `lst.append`, you are modifying the *value* that `lst` is a *name* for, which `arr` also happens to be a name for.  When you say `lst = 2`, you are rebinding the *name* `lst`, but you are not modifying the *value* that it previously referred to (and to which `arr` still refers).

Comment: *"lst and arr are no longer connected"* ... weeellll... Actually at least in CPython, `arr` now contains `lst` :-)